# Как вытащить значение из массива laravel

Tags: php, массивы, laravel

уважаемы программисты.

я вытаскивая массив $data->shop->offers->offer

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как мне вытащить с pickup-options, если:
$data->shop->offers->offer->pickup-options (выдает ошибку т.к "-" а не "_")

Comment: `offer->{'pickup-options'}`

Comment: Спасибо! @splash